# JQuery .post() method make loading stopped in IE before response is completed

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

Here is my js code, it request POST method to backend Spring Controller method that handles report generation and emails to user. And it can take more than a couple of minutes. 
It works in Firefox that the loading icon only stop when the response is back from back-end and displays message.

The problem is in IE, the loading icon stop after a few seconds before the response is back though back-end process works correctly. 
How can it be achieved in IE like in Firefox?

```
...    
var data = $("#myForm").serialize();  
var url = "<c:url value='${emailUrl}'/>";
$.post(url, data, function(response) {

    if(response=='success') {
        document.getElementById('statusMsg').innerHTML="Email is sent successfully.";
    }else if(response=='Error') {
        document.getElementById('statusMsg').innerHTML="Error occurs";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('statusMsg').innerHTML="Error occurs";
   }
});
...
```

Tested in IE8 and above.

Any input is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Even I had issues with $.POST() in IE so i used $.ajax().

> $.ajax( {
>
> ```
> type:'POST',
> url:'/account/alert/edit',
> cache:false,
> async:true,
> global:false,
> dataType:"html",
> data:"model=" + $('#alert').serialize(),
> timeout:10000,
> success:function(recept)
> {
>     alert('sucess !\nReceived data :\n' + recept);
> },
> error:function()
> {
>     alert('failed.');
> } });
> ```

Comment: sorry this extra " is typo error. Let me check with you code.